# Vue: Set active class - get current DOM element

Tags: vue.js

I try to set a class "active" on the currently selected element. I don' use `v-for`. When clicking the element, I set event.target to the "selected" property. On each element I want to compare the current element with the one stored in "selected". But how do I get the current element?.

Or if there is a simpler way to achieve it, that would be interesting to see.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/galivan/wdvc6txy/)

Template:

```
<div id="app">
  <button :class="{'active': selected === ''}" @click="test($event)">{{ message }}</button>
  <button :class="{'active': selected === ''}" @click="test($event)">{{ message }}</button>
  <button :class="{'active': selected === ''}" @click="test($event)">{{ message }}</button> 
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Vue',
    selected: ''
  },

  methods: {

      test(event){
           console.log(event.target)
      this.selected = event.target        //set selected to the DOM element

    }
  }

})
```

CSS:

```
.active{
  background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this… ?

```
<div id="app">
  <button :class="{'active': selected === 'a'}" @click="selected = 'a'">{{ message }}</button>
  <button :class="{'active': selected === 'b'}" @click="selected = 'b'">{{ message }}</button>
  <button :class="{'active': selected === 'c'}" @click="selected = 'c'">{{ message }}</button> 
</div>
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/6gxz9y8q/

---

You can also use [watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) to detect when values are changed. [(demo)](https://jsfiddle.net/f7zpj9em/), or run function as you did like [(demo)](https://jsfiddle.net/t7nogqm6/) or [(demo)](https://jsfiddle.net/qeyonxwh/), but **don't do something like** [(demo)](https://jsfiddle.net/fLq1yoxn/)

Comment: Nice solutions, so it can be solved without using the DOM elements.